# Searching on multiple checkboxes

Tags: search, checkboxes

I've got a question that I can't seem to get fixed all by myself... I've got a search form and each entry has got field with some checkboxes (in this case these are options). Now I'd like to search when they check multiple checkboxes but I can't seem to get that to work...
I've set up a form in which I'm fetching a parameter and just to test it with 2 checkboxes checked I've split them up in 'week1' and 'week2' like so:

```
{% set week_search_query =  week1 ~ ' ' ~ week2  %}
```

I've tried the same with 'and' and '&' in between the quotes but can't seem to get it to work, while with the 'week1' alone like so:

```
{% set week_search_query =  week1 %}
```

it works perfectly. (if I print out the content of 'week_search_query' in this case I get

> weken2017:41

with weken2017 as fieldname and 41 as value). 
But what I'd like to to is search by 2 checked checkboxes at once as in the first example, so I can:

```
craft.entries.search(week_search_query)
```

All help is welcome, I feel like quite a newbie ATM :-)

Comment: So, I've been able to find part of the solution, and I can find an "AND" solution like so: weken2017:'42, 43'
Now that I got that working I discovered I actually need an "OR" solution, so the search goes on and all help is still appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating answer as question was updated

As I see it, you want to find any and all entries where the field `weken2017` has either the value `42` or `43`.

Assuming that I have understood this much correctly, `{% set entries = craft.entries.search(['OR', 'weken2017:42', 'weken2017:43']) %}`

Comment: My bad, it was the end of the workday, of course I ran it through search, edited my question :-). I want to run the week_search_query through the search function :-)

Comment: No worries, it happens to the best of us. Updated my answer now to reflect upon your updated question :)